If "averaged" derivative is zero, the function is constant?
It is a simple elementary fact that if a function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable everywhere and its derivative is everywhere zero, then it is constant. But I have just discovered a new interesting concept which resembles derivative a lot and I wonder if it shares this property with the standard derivative.
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. We say $f$ has "averaged" derivative $C$ at point $x_0$ iff $t\mapsto\frac{2}{t}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t}f(x)dx$ has derivative $C$ at $t=0$ (this function converges to $2f(x_0)$ as $t\rightarrow0$, so we define $0\mapsto 2f(x_0)$ and then take the derivative at $t=0$). This derivative agrees with the standard derivative if the standard derivative exists at a point. My question is: if a function has "averaged" derivative 0 at all points, is it necessarily constant?
I have proven this in case when the function locally has bounded variation because then I can use AC-singular decomposition, play with it a bit and derive a contradiction easily, but general case obviously requires another idea.

If $f$ is constant $C$, then the function you defined is constant $2C$ because the integral is $t\cdot C$

@Callus-ReinstateMonica You are right, I messed up the definiton because my intuition is geometric, not analytical. I am sorry, give me a minute to fix this. EDIT: Actually, it was good. You should take the derivative of $2C$, not the $2C$ itself.

I haven't thought this through but the definition seems related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

@ronno I thought that too but could not find a useful connection between the two. I believe there exists an essential difference. I might be wrong.

@VarunVejalla I am sorry for this imprecision, let me address your question in the post.

@VarunVejalla Is it clear now?

@VarunVejalla My bad, I fixed it now. Thank you

One possible way to approach this: show that if the averaged derivative is equal to some continuous function on an open interval, then the standard derivative is equal to that same function as well. It's stronger than you need though (and maybe harder to show).

For continuous $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ we consider the function
$$
\begin{align}
 F_{x_0}(t) &= \begin{cases}
 \frac{2}{t}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t}f(x) \, dx & \text{ if } t \ne 0 \\
2 f(x_0) & \text{ if } t = 0 
\end{cases} \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 f(x_0 + ty) \, dy \, .
\end{align}
$$
We want to show that if  $F_{x_0}'(0)$ exists and is zero for all $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ then $f$ is constant.
Actually we can show the following stronger statement which resembles the mean value theorem:

If $a < b$ and $F_{x_0}'(0)$ exists for all $x_0 \in (a, b)$ then
$$
 f(b)-f(a) = F_{x_0}'(0) \cdot (b-a)
$$
for some $x_0 \in (a, b)$.

Proof: Let $a < b$ and assume that $F_{x_0}'(0)$ exists for all $x_0 \in (a, b)$. Similarly as in the proof of the mean value theorem we define the function
$$
 g(x) = f(x) - \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} (x-a)
$$
which is continuous and satisfies $g(a) = g(b)$, and for $x_0 \in(a, b)$ the corresponding function
$$
 G_{x_0}(t) = 2 \int_0^1 g(x_0 + ty) \, dy
$$
A simple calculation shows that $G_{x_0}(t)$ and $F_{x_0}(t)$ are related by
$$
  G_{x_0}(t) = F_{x_0}(t) - 2 \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} (x_0 - a + \frac 12 t) $$
and therefore
$$ \tag{$*$}
 G_{x_0}'(0) =  F_{x_0}'(0) - \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \, .
$$
It remains to show that $G_{x_0}'(0)=0$ for some $x_0 \in (a, b)$. Remember that $g(a) = g(b)$, so that $g$ necessarily has a (weak) maximum or a (weak) minimum at some point $x_0 \in (a, b)$. In the case of a maximum we have, with some $\delta > 0$,
$$
\begin{align}
  &g(x) \le g(x_0) \text{ for } |x - x_0| < \delta \\
  \implies &G_{x_0}(t) \le G_{x_0}(0) \text{ for }  |t| < \delta \\
  \implies &G_{x_0}'(0) = 0 \, .
\end{align}
$$
In the same way we get $G_{x_0}'(0) = 0$ if $g$ has a minimum at $x_0$, and that finishes the proof.

Wow! Turned out the answer was elementary and simple just like with the standard derivative. Excellent solution. I'll just add the conclusion I see now: If function $f$ is "averaged"-differentiable everywhere and its "averaged" derivative is equal to standard derivative of some function, then "averaged" and standard derivative agree for that function $f$.
